# Facebook pixel form submission tracking on gatsbyjs

Tags: reactjs, facebook, gatsby

I'm trying to find a way on Gatsbyjs site to add custom Facebook pixel conversion when visitors submit the contact form. Couldn't figure it out even using facebook pixel documentation.

The plugin that I'm using - https://github.com/gabefromutah/gatsby-plugin-facebook-pixel

The event that I need to track is:

`fbq('track', 'Lead', {content_name: 'ContactForm'});`

Is it the best way to do it through button click on the contact form? If so, how do I add it in?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This plugin ([`gatsby-plugin-facebook-pixel`](https://github.com/gabefromutah/gatsby-plugin-facebook-pixel)) only works in production build (i.e `gatsby build && gatsby serve`), perhaps that's why you're not seeing any tracking?

It sounds like you only want to track successful submission? If so, you might want to avoid only tracking button click and instead track after the submission's been received. For example, if you're using fetch to send your data, it might look roughly like so:

```js
const submitHandler = (data) => fetch(url, { 
  method: 'POST', 
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    if (res.ok) {
      fbq('track', ...)
    }
  })
  .catch(err => ...)
```

Comment: Hi, I know this is super old but I'm wondering if you know if this method still works? I.e. the gatsby-plugin-facebook-pixel?

Comment: @RwzrQ I haven't used Gatsby in years unfortunately — you could give the plugin a try to see if it still work